# Assumption when calculating distance between 2 lat-lngs using haversine formula?

Tags: gps, location, distance, latitude-longitude, haversine

I am would like to check if a pair of lat-lngs are within 10 meters of distance between each other. Is there any part after the decimal that we can ignore when calculating distance using haversine formula?

For eg, take these two lat lngs

```
128.228522,10.9282247607
128.228579,10.9282609467
```

The distance between them is ~ 6.9 meters
AND

distance between

```
101.228522,30.9282247607
101.228579,30.9282609467
```

is ~ 6.3 meters 

AND
distance between

```
98.998522,30.2282247607
98.998579,30.2282609467
```

again is ~ 6.3 meters

If you see all these pairs of lat-lngs, they are all similar upto 4 decimals points and are all less than 10 meters apart. But can I say this for sure? Is there any scenario where this assumption will not hold true?

Answer (score 0):

Four decimal place difference in lat-lon coodinates is generally ~10 meters apart. However, the horizontal distance between the coodinates becomes smaller as you get closer to the poles.

For example:

distance between

```
128.228522, 60.9282247607
128.228579, 60.9282609467
```

is ~5.1 meters

distance between

```
128.228522, 89.9282247607
128.228579, 89.9282609467
```

is ~4.0 meters

To make it clear, here are set of points with fixed longitudes values with a  relative delta of .0001 at different latitudes. The horizontal distance drops as you move towards the pole.

```
point 1          point 2         distance
128.2280, 10.0   128.2281, 10.0  10.9
128.2280, 60.0   128.2281, 60.0   5.6
128.2280, 80.0   128.2281, 80.0   1.9
128.2280, 89.0   128.2281, 89.0   0.19
```

Here are set of coordinates with a fixed longitude but different latutudes each having a .0001 relative difference. The vertical distance in each case is ~11.1 meters.

```
128.2280, 10.1234  128.2280, 10.1235
128.2280, 20.1234  128.2280, 20.1235
128.2280, 60.1234  128.2280, 60.1235
128.2280, 80.1234  128.2280, 80.1235
128.2280, 89.1234  128.2280, 89.1235
```